# Conditions that we can get from $P^2=P$ for $P \in L(V)$ where $V$ is finite-dimensional inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

This must imply $V=N(P) \oplus R(P)$.

Also, I've learned that $V=N(P) \oplus R(P)$ implies that $u-Pu$ can represent any element in $N(P)$.

However, I don't understand why this is possible to represent any vector in $N(P)$.

Doesn't this have to be $a-Pb$ for any $a,b \in V$?
Why can they share the same vector $u$?

Comment: Do you agree that $u - Pu$ is in $N(P)$? Suppose now that $u \in N(P),$ clearly $u = u - Pu.$

Comment: @WillM. Wow. Thank you very much!